# Convergence of an infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

[image: Sum from n = 0 to infinity of Cn*(4^n)]
[image: Sum from n = 0 to infinity of Cn*(-4^n) and sum from n = 0 to infinity of Cn*(-2^n)]

I feel the coefficient Cn has to be zero in order for the original series to converge, as the power series of 4^n will diverge as n - > ∞. Are there any other ways for this series to converge, and if so, will the convergence remain in an alternating series with bases of -2 and -4?

Comment: It's true that we need $C_n \to 0$ in order for the series to converge, but it doesn't need to be exactly zero by any means.  Consider $C_n = 1 / (4^n n^2)$, for instance.

Comment: See [If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n4^n$ is convergent, is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(-4)^n$ convergent as well?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234339/) and [If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ is convergent for $x=-3$, what can be said about convergence at $x=2$ and $x=3$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990244/)

Answer (score 1):

If
$c_n 
=\frac{(-1)^n}{n4^n}
$,
then
$\sum_{=1}^{\infty} c_n 4^n$
converges
(it's a alternating sum
with the terms decreasing to zero),
and
$\sum_{=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n c_n 4^n$
does not converge
(it's the well-known
harmonic sum).

If
$\sum_{=1}^{\infty} c_n 4^n$
converges,
then
$c_n 4^n \to 0$.
This is *necessary*
for the sum to converge.
Therefore,
for any $\epsilon > 0$,
there is an $N$
such that
$|c_n 4^n|
<\epsilon
$
for $n > N$.
In particular,
choosing $\epsilon = 1$,
there is an $N_1$
such that
$|c_n 4^n|
<1
$
for $n > N_1$.

Therefore,
for $n > N_1$,
$|c_n (-2)^n|
=|c_n 2^n|
=\dfrac{|c_n 4^n|}{2^n}
<\dfrac1{2^n}
$.
Since
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{2^n}$
converges,
so does
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n (-2)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that the values of $C_n$ must be $0$. For example, if $C_n=(\frac{1}{8})^n$ then our series would be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\frac{1}{8})^n4^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\frac{1}{2})^n$ which does converge.

It is not true that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n (-4)^n$ must converge. For an example, suppose $C_n=(-\frac{1}{4})^n\frac{1}{n+1}$. Then $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n 4^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\bigg(\frac{4}{4}\bigg)^n\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1}{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$$ which converges. However, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n (-4)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$$

which is the harmonic series, and diverges.

Comment: Nothing is saying that C_n is positive, is it?

Comment: @Did You're right, my mistake. I've hopefully fixed the error. I'll leave this answer as support to Marty's.